# Eric Martin Simplemodal OSX, open using code

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I want to be able to open the OSX Style Dialog simple modal by pressing a button, but only if the rest of the form has already been filled out. Right now I'm starting it by giving it the class osx demo

```
<input type='button' name='osx' value='Create Coupons' onClick = 'startModal();' class='osx demo'/>
```

I'd like to have it start in the onClick function

```
function startModal() {
if (daily) {
    createDailyModal();
} else {
    createFullModal();
}

if($('#enddate').val().indexOf("/") != -1){
         *code to start modal*
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can do this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd avoid the onClick in your html. Why? It's cleaner to work that part out in your jquery-script.

```
<input type='button' name='osx' value='Create Coupons' class='osx demo'/>
```

Then do

```
$("[name='osx']").click(function()
{
    if($('#enddate').val().indexOf("/") != -1)
    {
        *code to start modal*
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree with you to avoid the `onClick` in the html. But it's not always to best way to do it. Imagine you have a really large javascript and a lot of jQuery objects cached, having to cache that little element will cost you even more performance, so, in that case `onClick` is acceptable!

Comment: Oh absolutely @silentw it comes down to the size of your script.